# How to have a background picture in a folder on windows 7?

Tags: windows, background-image, special-folders

Ok so i was wondering if it was possible to write a program (any language) that could add, change, and/or remove a background picture for a folder on windows seven. On windows xp or older, you could accomplish this by editing the hidden file in every directory called "desktop.ini" and adding a code to the file that contained the path of your picture. But this method was discontinued on windows vista and windows 7. I wanted to set a custom background picture that would appear behind the icons instead of the default white background. I have no clue how to do this so any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow no one has an answer for this question! aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Windows 7 Folder Background Changer: [Download from Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Windows-7-Folder-Background-Changer.shtml)